file sharing using Amazon S3 and AWS Step Functions
I was trying to deploy a serverless application on AWS following this guide.
One of the feature of this app is that it sends the notificstion to the recepient of file. However the write of this guide kept the "sendNotifications.ts" lambda function under SERVERLESS-FILE-SHARE/CDK/src/functions/share/ folder as placeholder where we can use our own logic to send the notification. Here is the code for sendNotifications.ts
import { wrapHandler } from '../../lib/observability';
import { ShareRequestWithUserAndFileInfo } from '../../types';

const lambdaHandler = async (event: ShareRequestWithUserAndFileInfo): Promise<ShareRequestWithUserAndFileInfo> => {
  /**
   * This lambda function is intentionally left blank for you to
   * implement your own notification mechanism, e.g. sending an email with Amazon SES
   * or sending a chat notification.
   *
   * Note: the download link is in the format: {API_URL}/download/{fileId}
   */
  return event;
};

export const handler = wrapHandler(lambdaHandler);

Since I am not a developer and I am stuck here. Can someone please help me with this? how I can enable the send notifications feature with this serverless app.

I would decide what kind of notification was appropriate and then search for examples of how to do that. Here's an example of sending email via SES.
